# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'xlxswriter'

Tags: python

Language: Python 3.8.3 
I faced this error when I was importing my xlxs file `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'xlxswriter'`

```
import xlxswriter

import pandas as pd

from pandas import DataFrame

path = ('mypath.xlxs')

xl = pd.ExcelFile(path)

print(xl.sheet_names)
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of typing xlsx, type xlsx like this:

```
import xlsxwriter

import pandas as pd

from pandas import DataFrame

path = ('mypath.xlsx')

xl = pd.ExcelFile(path)

print(xl.sheet_names)
```

It'll work.

Answer (score 1):

The module name is xlsxwriter not xlxswriter, so replace that line with:

```
import xlsxwriter
```